# Xcode 7 (7A220) don't show the simulators versions anymore

Tags: ios, xcode7

After installing 8.4 simulators, Xcode toolbar (and the *Product>Destination* menu) only show what is seems to be a UID next to the models and not the iOS version as before, like this:

[image]

Is there any way to make Xcode to show the iOS version as before? This really annoying when I need to test different devices/versions.

**Edit 1:** Midhun MP solution will fix this problem, but in my case it will be a lot of work, I don't know why but I have 4 entries for every device and version:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to restart Xcode? It's known to have silly bugs like this.

Comment: Yes... I tried... No use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename the simulators to your preferred name.

1. Open Xcode
2. Choose Window menu
3. Choose Device
4. Right click on the simulator
5. Choose Rename
6. Enter new name and Press enter

**Step 1 to Step 3**

[image: Step 1-3]

Step 4 to Step 6

[image: Step 4-6]

Comment: Thanks! That certainly can solve the issue, but it seems there's 4 entries for every device and version (?!), so it will take a lot of time to get this right, Is there any other way?

Comment: @Raspu: Is duplicate devices show same version ? It seems a Xcode bug then.

Comment: Yes they do, but with different identifiers. See the edit in my question.

Comment: (If nobody else offers a better solution in a few days, I will mark your answer as accepted anyway, thanks!)

Comment: @Raspu: If you find any solution, please post it as an answer ;) . There are options to hide some of those devices from the run menu of Xcode. (I know that is also not an easy solution for this problem.)

Comment: Yes, I will certainly do that if I find a better solution :). I also saw the hide option, and if nothing else work, I will work with that.